# Find the missing numbers 1, 3, 6, ?, ?, ?, 45, 55

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

> 1, 3, 6, ?, ?, ?, 45, 55

I asked the person who gave this to me and they assured me that it's correct.

After an hour, I've given up :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 1, 3, 6, **15**, **28**, **36**, 45, 55

Because

> These are the triangular numbers whose digits are in non-decreasing order.

Comment: Where are 10 and 21?

Comment: Their digits are not in nondecreasing order.